# ASP.net Linq To TSQL Caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-migration

I'm using ASP.Net and Database-Migrations atm.
I'm adding some functionality to my Classes to get some extra Data through the objects.

```
public IQueryable<CounterDiscussionThread> Answers
{
    get
    {
        return db.CounterDiscussionThreads.Where(e => e.Parent == CounterDiscussionThreadId);
    }
}

public CounterDiscussionThread LastPost
{
    get
    {
        return db.CounterDiscussionThreads.OrderByDescending(e => e.TimePosted)
                                          .First(e => e.CounterDiscussionThreadId == CounterDiscussionThreadId || e.Parent == CounterDiscussionThreadId);
    }
}
```

Will these make multiple DB queries if I call them multiple times in the same thread or will it automaticly cache the results?

Additional Info:
db base DBContext

Example:
`<%# Item.LastPost.TimePosted.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") %>` and `<%# Item.LastPost.TimePosted.ToString("t") %>`. Will this result in 1 or 2 database queries?

Comment: Does `db` base `DbContext`?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Entity Framework since you mention database migrations. But similar to Linq to SQL, the data context will cache the results and use them as much as possible to prevent to go back to SQL if they are called within the same data context instance.

Looking at your example, if everything is setup correctly (same `DbContext`, caching is enabled, etc), only one database query should happen.